# How to addColumn character varying(3)[] for Phinx

Tags: php, postgresql, phinx

How do I add a column using Phinx of type `character varying(3)[]` using their `addColumn` api?

Digging into the source code seems like it might not be a [supported feature](https://github.com/cakephp/phinx/blob/master/src/Phinx/Db/Adapter/PostgresAdapter.php)?

Answer (score 0):

Phinx support [custom types](https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/migrations.html#custom-column-types-default-values) and you can forgo type check and write your own custom types:

```
addColumn(
    'MY_COLUMN_NAME',
    Literal::from('CHARACTER VARYING(3)[]'),
    [
        'null' => true,
        'comment' => 'SOME COMMENT ABOUT MY COLUMN'
    ])
```